# save() return true in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

Now, I have a model I want to save.

code:

```
//I have a lot of tables
//tables :day_01,day_02,day_03....day_31;
$objData = $objModel->setTable("day_01")->where(['user_id'=>123])->first();
$intNum = $objData->num;
//I made a mistake specifically. table `day_02` don't have user_id=123 data
$objData->setTable("day_02");
$objData->num = $intNum+20; 
$isRs = $objData->save();
dd($isRs)//true,this is a mistake.it didn't change data
```

So now, How can I check that `save()` was successful, even if it didn't change data???

sql:

    `//DB::listen
    select * from`day_01`where (`user_id`= '123') limit 1 ;
    update`day_02`set`num`= '20' where`user_id`= 123;`

Comment: Did you mean in "day_2" table the record width user_id 123 is not stored?

Comment: yes,"day_2" table don't has the record with user_id=123

Comment: https://laravel.io/forum/orm-function-savebug

Comment: As a rule of thumb, one model corresponds to exactly one table. What you're doing here looks like a very bad way of solving a problem. In fact I'd suggest you take a step back and ask yourself whether you really need 31 tables instead of a single table with an additional "day" column.